# Vector subspace contains linear combinations of its elements

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V $ be a vector space over the field $ F $. Let $ W\neq\emptyset $ be a subspace of $ W $, in the sense that given $ v $, $ w $ in $ W $ then $ v+w $ belongs to $ W $, and given $ \alpha\in F $, then $ \alpha v\in V $.

I'm having an hard time proving that, assuming this definition, all linear combinations of elements of $ W $ belong to $ W $.

Let $ \left\{w_1,\dots,w_n\right\} $ be a family of elements of the subspace. If $ \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iw_i $ is a linear combination, then we can split that sum as $ \sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_iw_i+\sum_{i=k+1}^n\alpha_iw_i $ for some $ 1\leqq k<n $. From here I have no idea about how to continue.

Is a mathematical induction argument legitimate in this case? If so, why, since I'm missing it?

---

Of course is immediate to prove that $ W=\langle W\rangle $, where $ \langle W\rangle=\bigcap_{\substack{U\leqq V\\ U\supset W}}U $ is the subspace generated by $ W $, but my concern is with the above method of proof.

Comment: You can prove it by induction.

Comment: Use induction. All linear combinations of $1$ element are in $W$, right? This follows from the definition. Now try to do the inductive step.

Comment: Use induction, since the subspace definition gives you the case for $\{w_1,w_2\}$.

Comment: I don't know if I could make use of mathematical induction, since my aim is not to prove this statement for all $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, but for all the linear combinations of elements of $ W $ (or I'm simply making a mess with indexing). In fact, my very question might be rephrased as "is a mathematical induction argument legitimate in this case?". (I have included this comment in OP).

Comment: Why not? For $n=1$ all linear combinations are indeed in $W$, simply by definition. Suppose for some $n-1$ all linear combinations of $n-1$ elements of $W$ are in $W$. Now take any linear combination with $n$ elements...

Comment: In this case I would prove that for all $ n $, a linear combination of $ n $ elements of $ W $ is still in the subspace. Okay, I think I'm fine with that and only messed up with indices (at first I was thinking about the $ \operatorname{span} $ of a finite family of $ w_i $s indexed by an arbitrary finite set $ I $, but then such a family would have been in bijection with a finite sets of naturals). In fact, the proposition proved when checking that $ \langle W\rangle=\left\{\sum_i a_iw_i:\text{$ a_i\in F $ and $ w_i\in W $ for all $ i\leqq k $, $ k\in\mathbb{N} $}\right\} $ is pretty similar.